# Ember build not picking up changes to environment.js

Tags: ember.js

I have a working configuration in my environment.js, but want to add a variable. I placed the pageSize variable like so: `var ENV = {
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
    },
    modulePrefix: 'fdms-admin',
    environment: environment,
    ROOT_URL: process.env.ROOT_URL,
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    pageSize: 100,
    baseURL: '/admin/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
    ...`

When I run ember build and place the assets folder inside of my Java project, the changes to the config are not being picked up. The pageSize variable is undefined on the ENV object. Any ideas?

I usually test by running ember server --proxy http://localhost:8080 --environment local, and the pageSize variable show up just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which ember version you use but environment variables are placed inside meta tag with name set to ember app that you created and content. So when you say I copied the javascript files did you also included the meta tag after building for production mode

```
ember build --environment production
```

Under dist the index.html file contains this line

```
<meta name="APPNAME/config/environment" content="....
```

So after you copy script files your html file that loads them should include this meta tag as well. I have seen somewhere that this is possible to export env into js file but forgot how it is setup. In most cases config vars are stored in meta tag.

Hope it helps

Comment: This was it, TYVM! Beforehand I was just copying over the assets folder before, which I believe works as intended as long as you aren't changing the config.